# fgetc is always returning value 1

Tags: c, printf, eof, fgetc, getc

there is the following function:

```
void readAndPrint(FILE * f) {
    int c;

    while(c = fgetc(f) != EOF) {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
}
```

In the main() body I used the following code to use the above function:

```
FILE * pFile;

pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

readAndPrint(pFile)
```

;

Whatever I put into myfile.txt, the program prints out ones. 
For example, for abc, 111 is printed out.

I know that c in the function should be declared int to properly compare it to EOF. Also, I expected an int code from the ASCII set for each char in the text file to be printed out (97 for a, ...). I cannot figure out why it prints out 'ones'... Does you know the reason why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(c = fgetc(f) != EOF)` - Here first `fgetc(f) != EOF` this condition is happening and the result `1` or `0` is assigned to `c`. Always a condition check returns `TRUE`(`1`) or `FALSE` (`0`).

Do `while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)`